# How to land on another page when pressing a button and somehow save the id set in the button?

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-2.2

What i'm trying to do is to create a bike booking method. On my map i have different markers which represent different locations and when clicking the marker a pop-up opens. I'm trying to set a button in the pop-up which on click to send me to the Booking page, but somehow i need to know from which 'Station' the user wanted to book a bike. I'm not entirely sure how to do that, but here is what i tried so far.

Here is where my button is set in pop-up :

```
                else {
                    contentString[i] = '<div id="content">' +
                        '<div id="siteNotice">' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '<h2 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">' +
                        data[i].name +
                        '</h2>' +
                        '<div id="bodyContent">' +
                        '<p><h6> Biciclete: </h6>' +
                        data[i].nrOfBikes +
                        '<div> Biciclete Libere:' + data[i].nrOfAvailableBikes + ' </div>' +
                        '<div><input type="submit" id="' + data[i].id + '" value="Make a reservation" class="btn btn-outline-warning" onClick="SendToReservation(this)"></div>';
                }
```

Here is how i'm trying to send to the C# method:

```
function SendToReservation(button) {
    $.post("/Reservation/Reservation?id=" + $(button)[0].id,
        function (data, status) {
            if (status == "success") {
                smth smth;
            }
        });
}
```

Here is how my Booking page is rendered:

```
        public ActionResult Reservation()
        {            
            return View();
        }
```

And after completing the form it should come to another method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Reservation(params){
         do smth here
}
```

And here is how my Booking page looks like:

```
<div class="row text-center">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <form asp-action="Reservation">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" />
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="UserFirstName" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="UserFirstName" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="UserFirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="UserSurname" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="UserSurname" class="form-control " />
            <span asp-validation-for="UserSurname" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="IdentityCardNumber" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="IdentityCardNumber" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="IdentityCardNumber" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="StartTime" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="StartTime" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="StartTime" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="EndTime" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="EndTime" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="EndTime" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-outline-success" />
            <a asp-action="UserMap" asp-controller="UserMap" class="btn btn-outline-dark">Back to List</a>
        </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any idea on how i should store the station id in order to be used in the `Reservation` controller?

Comment: Your code is sending a POST request to the server, passing an `id` param inside the URL, i.e. as GET parameter. Most of the code in your question is irrelevant, this is just about reading a GET param server-side. Which should be well-documented and very straightforward. I suspect the problem is something else: you're using AJAX, so a crucial part of this question is what exactly your `smth smth;` is. Note that an AJAX request will *not* navigate to a new page; if you want to programmatically submit a POST form and navigate to the result, AJAX is the wrong approach.

Comment: Hm, i see. What i was planning to do, was when pressing the button, land on the booking page, get all that information in the c# controller, work with it, save it in the database, and after all this is done, come back to the javascript and open a success alert or something. But i need to know from which marker i was trying to make the booking in order to be able to work with it in the c# method.

Comment: Yeah, landing on the booking page isn't going to work with an AJAX request (unless you call `location = "some_url";` in the success method, in which case you don't need an AJAX call). The simplest possible way to solve this to put an `<a>` in place of the button and set its href to `"/Reservation/Reservation?id=" + data[i].id`

Comment: `and after all this is done, come back to the javascript and open a success alert or something` this sounds like you want to keep the map loaded (and *not* navigate elsewhere); why not put the registration form into the marker popup, add the `id` as `<input type="hidden">`, then send all data using `$.post()`? In the success method, you remove the popup and show a confirmation message.

Comment: Yeah, you're right with both of the solutions, didn't think that deep. I didn't have any problem with navigating to another page, that's what i actually wanted to do, because it seemed to me a lot harder to create a form there based on my model, and than send it back to the controller method to do everything else. But i'll try in both ways and the one which fits, it sits. Thanks a lot.